# Can npm-check-updates lock a few dependency when doing ncu -ua?

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies, package.json

We are using [`npm-check-updates`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-check-updates) to update our `package.json` dependency.

We have serious issues with it because we have many small projects that need to have a fixed version for a certain dependency.

I am a module writer and we do not want to fix version for our users in our `package.json`, but we want to support up to a version voluntary on our side.

Most of the time, when we build something **on top of**, we want to stick to show the dependency set by the core one.

We found `ncu -ua` to be an excellent command when we do not have a fixed version in our package, but we must proceed to a manual edition of `package.json` when we do have fixed version.

Is there a way using a file or whatever, to set a list of ignored dependency when using `ncu -ua`?

That would save us a lot of time.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`npm-check-updates` has a flag `-x, --reject` to ignore certain packages when checking for updates.

```bash
ncu -u -x mobx,query-string
```

Will update all outdated dependencies except mobx and query-string (dropped IE11 support at certain versions). Make sure not to add any spaces after the comma when listing the dependencies.

To have a place where to write down the dependencies that shouldn't be updated anymore, the above command can be added to the scripts inside `package.json` like this:

```json
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "scripts": {
    "update": "ncu -u -x mobx,query-string"
  }
}
```

Always remember to update through `npm run update`.

Answer (score 13):

This can also be setup in a `.ncurc.json` file in the project's root directory (next to package.json, where 'ncu' is being run), like so:

```js
{
  "reject": [
    "mobx",
    "query-string"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Nice! Beware that "upgrade": true is like running ncu -u, but it can be removed from the file.

Comment: @AugustoBarreto -- good point, it's not really relevant to the question so I removed it.